# Strange behaviour with this struct shallow copy?

Tags: c++

I've defined the following data structure which has the intent of providing a get_next() method which returns the iterator pointing at the next required_configuration. If `required_explorations` is empty or has reached the end, it returns it pointing at the begin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using configuration_model = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;

struct doe_model {

    inline bool add_config(const std::string& config_id,
        const configuration_model& config,
        const int required_number_of_observations)
    {
        bool assignment_took_place = !required_explorations.insert_or_assign(config_id, config).second || !number_of_explorations.insert_or_assign(config_id, required_number_of_observations).second;
        next = required_explorations.end();
        return assignment_took_place;
    }

    inline void update_config(const std::string& config_id)
    {
        number_of_explorations.at(config_id)--;

        // remove the configuration in case we exausted all the explorations
        if (number_of_explorations.at(config_id) <= 0)
            remove_config(config_id);
    }

    inline void remove_config(const std::string& config_id)
    {
        required_explorations.erase(config_id);
        number_of_explorations.erase(config_id);
    }

    // this method returns the next configuration to explore
    // NOTE: the caller MUST check the pointer first.
    inline std::map<std::string, configuration_model>::iterator get_next()
    {
        // we may have an empty map or one with only a single configuration left
        if (required_explorations.empty() || next == required_explorations.end()) {
            std::cout << "Required explorations is empty or next at the end(), "
                         "returning the first pointer."
                      << std::endl;
            next = required_explorations.begin();
            return next;
        }

        next++;

        std::cout << "Returning a next pointer normally." << std::endl;
        return next;
    }

    // key is the configuration_id
    std::map<std::string, configuration_model> required_explorations;
    std::map<std::string, configuration_model>::iterator next;
    std::map<std::string, int> number_of_explorations;
};
```

I'm not that aware on the default shallow copy that it is generated for an assignment operator with this structure, but testing it I think the problem relies on the `next` iterator copy.

Running this returns `0` as expected (which is the first element).

```
int main()
{
    doe_model doe;
    doe.add_config("0", { { "threads", "29" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("1", { { "threads", "23" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("2", { { "threads", "20" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("3", { { "threads", "21" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("4", { { "threads", "22" } }, 4);

    auto it = doe.get_next();
    std::cout << it->first << "\t" << std::endl;
}
```

But running the following returns `4` which is the end.

```
int main()
{
    doe_model doe;
    doe.add_config("0", { { "threads", "29" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("1", { { "threads", "23" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("2", { { "threads", "20" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("3", { { "threads", "21" } }, 4);
    doe.add_config("4", { { "threads", "22" } }, 4);

    doe_model new_doe = doe;

    auto it = new_doe.get_next();
    std::cout << it->first << "\t" << std::endl;
}
```

Can someone give me some insight of what's going on behind the scenes?

*UPDATE* here's a real example of `doe_model` usage. There are some data members and other function calls which I'm not going to talk about since they aren't really needed in order to understand how `doe_model` is intended to be used. When `send_configuration` is called it needs to pull a new configuration from the doe structure and therefor the `get_next` method is needed to achieve that task returning a new configuration (different from the previous and which still has `number_of_explorations > 0`).

```
  void send_configuration(const client_id_t &name)
  {
    if (num_configurations_sent_per_iteration <= num_configurations_per_iteration)
    {
      auto configuration = doe.get_next();
      if (configuration != doe.required_explorations.end())
      {
        remote->send_message(
            {MESSAGE_HEADER + "/" + app_id.app_name + "^" + app_id.version + "^" + app_id.block_name + "/" + name + "/explore",
             configuration_to_json(configuration->second)});


        doe.update_config(configuration->first);

        num_configurations_sent_per_iteration++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you copy `doe`, the underlying map is copied, the iterator is copied as well, but it points to `doe.required_explorations`, not `new_doe.required_explorations`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member `next;` is copied, still referring to the other instance's `required_explorations`.

When you call `get_next()`, the comparison `next == required_explorations.end()` has undefined behaviour, it is only defined for iterators to the same container<sup>1</sup>.

Aside: In the case where `required_explorations` is empty, returning `required_explorations.begin()` and dereferencing it also has undefined behaviour.

1. If you are using C++14 or later, you can compare your iterator to a *value-initialised* iterator, which behaves like `end` for all containers. In C++11 you need a second iterator from the container to be safe.

Comment: Oh I see.. So defining a custom copy constructor and assignment operator should be right direction to go I suppose. Or there's something easier that can be done?

Comment: @Barnercart Unfortunately, yes, in general case. Or getting rid of iterators/references altogether.

Comment: @Barnercart I would advise getting rid of `next` and `get_next`, replaced with a `begin`/`end` that expose the map's `begin`/`end`

Comment: @Caleth thanks for the advice. I was planning on putting this on Code Reviews anyway once it was bugs/unexpected_behaviours free.

Comment: @Caleth I was thinking about your proposal but I need to loop through the map externally and since I need not to access the same element twice I need a method (`next`) that gives me the possibility of accessing always a different element (except when there's only a single element of course). Exposing the `begin/end` doesn't allow me to pick the next element in the "queue" from the caller side.

Comment: @Barnercart You'd call `begin` once, and each time you wanted to move to the next element you could use `++` or `std::advance` on the iterator. each time you'd compare against `end`. Then you don't need a member `next`, and can follow the rule of 0

Comment: @Caleth oh so you're saying basically to leave the iterator management to the caller end? Fact is that the caller right now is using `next` just once per function call. I'm going to update the question to show a real example of `doe_model` usage.